# XCode code coverage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

I would like to test my code completely with ***code coverage***. But I am not able to find how to make complete code coverage.

Here I have a simple test code to check code coverage.

**gist link:** https://gist.github.com/damodarpatel18/789dfc142fd492a56c556b844ce945e9 here is my sample code to test.

**LoginViewModel Code Coverage**

[image: Here is the code coverage for LoginViewModel]

**ViewController Code Coverage**

[image: Here is the code coverage for ViewController]

Can anyone explain about code coverage, How to make code completely testable?

**Here is my LoginSpec**

[image: LoginSpec]

Comment: It's all about covering all scenarios, a general testing rule is to write 3 cases that creates the expected result while you have 3 tests that give an unexpected result. It's not needed for a full test coverage, but it is good practice

Comment: Can u please explain in my scenario. I have added LoginSpec to check test cases, What to do in ViewContoller submitAction and inside LoginViewModel login function? sorry, I'm new to test cases.

Comment: In your *LoginViewModel Code Coverage* you should cover *false* statement from the `login` method. Add another test case eg. "testLoginFailed" with following line of code `let isLoginSuccess = login?.login(userName: "Damodar", password: "")` and verify that isLoginSuccess if false. It's also good to have similar test but with empty userName.